# Send XML with JQuery to port device inside my local network

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, url, port

I would like to introduce my problem, I have two different computers in the same local network.

One running the Javascript code.

And the other is a Windows computer with a device connected to the port 5254.

I would like to send XML's from the first computer to the second device that it's allocated in the port 5254 of the second computer, using Javascript.

My actual proposal it's the following:

```
function exampleFunction() {
var xmlDocument =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
    '<version>1.0</version>';

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.1.17:5254',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        data: xmlDocument
    },
    dataType: 'text/xml',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('result');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, tranStatus, errorThrown) {
   
        alert(

            'Status: ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText + '. ' +
            'Response: ' + jqXHR.responseText
        );
    }
    });
}
```

The XML's is just an example.

I'm not currently able to do that I'm always getting the error function.

I saw that I'm probably not able to connect to other port due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
But I don't know if it's specific to my problem or not, or if there are other alternatives to correct that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by assuming that "yes, you have a different origin" and then the recipient of the request has to be a web serrver that supports CORS

Comment: `$.support.cors = true;` — That's an internal property used by jQuery to detect if the browser supports CORS. Overriding it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "I'm not currently able to do that I'm always getting the error function." — And what error do you get? And what other errors are reported in the console since JS has limited access to the details of network errors for security reasons.

Comment: Okey I deleted the Cors part. — Sorry, for my explanations.  When I was saying "I'm always getting error function" is that the alert that appears to me is the one which is inside the function called 'error' and not success function. Also as you said nothing is outputted in the console.log I didn't know the security reasons.

Comment: And what does the error say?  It's alerting jqXHR.status , jqXHR.statusText, and  jqXHR.responseText all of which may have clues about what the problem is … but you're keeping them a secret.

Comment: "Status: 0 error. Response: undefined" that's all that is saying to me. So probably is not doing nothing. Sorry again